# css box with arrow disappears when adding scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an arrow in the top middle of a box generated by CSS before and after suedo elements. However when I add `overflow-y:scroll;` to the box the arrow generated by the css disappears.

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/aaronmallen/FP5jr/

**CSS:**

```
#notesdisplay {
    position: relative;
    background: #E8E8E8 ;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    display: box;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
}
#notesdisplay:after, #notesdisplay:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#notesdisplay:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#notesdisplay:before {
    border-color: rgba(21, 83, 132, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
    border-width: 14px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -14px;
}

#notesdisplay2 {
    position: relative;
    background: #E8E8E8 ;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    display: box;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#notesdisplay2:after, #notesdisplay2:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#notesdisplay2:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#notesdisplay2:before {
    border-color: rgba(21, 83, 132, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
    border-width: 14px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -14px;
}
```

Comment: please show your html structure. Or create a jsfiddle with the problem.

Comment: down vote and don't explain why? really nice

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iCuNaC/1/edit    -- can you please check it out

Comment: that's the expected result. You're saying to hide the overflow, and those :before/:after are overflowing... Just add a div wrapping the text, make it 100% x 100% and overflow:scroll it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing what Francisco Presencia said with a div wrapping the text works..

new css:

```
#notestext {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#notesdisplay {
    position: relative;
    background: #E8E8E8 ;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    display: box;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
}
#notesdisplay:after, #notesdisplay:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#notesdisplay:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#notesdisplay:before {
    border-color: rgba(21, 83, 132, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
    border-width: 14px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -14px;
}
```

new html:

```
<div id="notesdisplay"><div id="notestext">TEXT</div></div>
```